# Check if two inputs have same index in 2 different lists

Tags: python-3.x, list

Hi everyone i need help for my computing project but cant find an answer on google. Im trying to make a basic login system and have 2 lists, one list with usernames and one with passwords:

```
usernames[username1, username2, username3, etc]

passwords[password1, password2, password3, etc]
```

i want to ask the user for a username and password input and check if they are in the corresponding lists. However i cant work out how to do it without someone being able to login using their username and someone else's password.

My current code is:

```
def Login():

    usernames = [username1, username2, username3]
    passwords = [password1, password2, password3]
    user = input("Please enter your username: ")
    pw = input("Please enter password: ")
    x = 0
    for x in range(len(usernames)):
        if user == usernames[x] and pw == passwords[x]:
            print("Login Successful")
        elif user == usernames[x] and pw !=  passwords[x]:
            print("Password does not match")
            Login()
        else:
            print("User not recognised")
            Login()
        x = x + 1
```

I want to be able to check what position the username they gave me is in the list and then look for that position in the passwords list and if that password is the one they gave, they can login.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `zip` to iterate over your list. And use `enumerate` if you need to find the position.

**Demo:**

```
def Login():
    usernames = ['username1', 'username2', 'username3']
    passwords = ['password1','password2', 'password3']
    user = input("Please enter your username: ")
    pw = input("Please enter password: ")

    for i, x in enumerate(zip(usernames, passwords)):
        if user == x[0] and pw == x[1]:
            print("Login Successful")
            print("Index Position ", i)
        elif user == usernames[x] and pw !=  passwords[x]:
            print("Password does not match")
            print("Index Position ", i)
            Login()
        else:
            print("User not recognised")
            Login()
```